# VB return procedure

Tags: vb.net

```
Function f(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal z As Integer, ByVal w As Integer, ByRef t As String) As String
    If Length(x) < w Then      // Definition for Length below
      Return t
    End If
    If y = z Then
        t = t + SubStr(x, w, 1)    // Definition for SubStr below
        z = 1
    Else
        z = z + 1
    End If
    w = w + 1
    Return f(x, y, z, w, t)

End Function
Function f1(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As Integer) As String
    Return (f(x, y, 1, 1, ""))
End Function
```

I am not a VB programmer, but I assumed for the most part that the syntax is C like, I received the program above from a non-technical recruiter with the following input **f1("enritcde3 dtyeds4t8", 2)** . From my understanding the following output would be **(“enritcde3 dtyeds4t8”,2,2,2,“”)**
. Am I missing something???

Comment: To clarify a little, the question was to provide the output, which I did and they told me i was wrong, which I was confused, but wouldn't provide me with what they thought was the correct output, even after I asked, since I was confused

Comment: What do you think you are missing?

Comment: I dont know, For what their stating I was wrong, so after looking at it serveral times, I dont know what they are referring to?

Comment: The function returns a string. Even in C, the output would never be `(“enritcde3 dtyeds4t8”,2,2,2,“”)`.

Comment: Oh I see. Guess I wasn't paying attention to that recursion part of things. I know how recursion works, just have overlooked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just converted it over to Vb.Net and the output is "nice test".

Its parsing the even position characters in the string excluding the space.

Comment: so basically going through a loop until **t** is returned

Comment: Don't mistake recursion for a loop. They are two distinct things.

Comment: Check out this [artical](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/.net-developer-basics---recursive-algorithms/) on recusion.

Answer (score -1):

There are two functions in your code block.  The f1 function only has 2 parameters, and it then calls the f function using hard coded values for the z, w and t parameters.  So, in a sense, you're both right.

Comment: No the question is what is the output which I provided and they stated I was wrong